# Is Adobe Flash Player installer redirect due to a malware?

Tags: malware, virus, macos, flash

When I go to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ 'Install Now' will redirect me to their homepage without downloading the update or any explanation.

What could be going on? Is some malware redirecting me?

(Running Mac 10.8.4 tried both Safari and FF)

**Note**: I have Ghostery and Adblock installed, tried disabling them. I do not think it's malware as no one seems to have the same symptoms after googling, and I would suspect a malicious redirect among other oddities.

Comment: Maybe its malware preventing you from installing?

Comment: it's working for me. I have both ghostery and adblock + installed

Comment: Enable the Omniture tracker (it's Adobe Analytics's and if blocked, breaks their scripts).

Comment: @rook I would't call malware something that prevents you from installing the real malware, aka Flash. ;)

Comment: Same problem analysed on MacOS 10.9, 10.10, with many versions of Firefox.

Comment: Flash is Malware.  See the comments in this question:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148884/does-the-flash-installer-use-an-encrypted-download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think this is any malware.
The `Omniture tracker` blocking in `Ghostery` will block Adobe Flash Player to terminate correctly (comment by anonymous user n° 34727, verified personally).
It does consider to track us more important than to perform a correct install.

Unfortunatly since many years and many versions of Adobe Flash Player installer, this is the way that this installer is behaving. 
The core of the problem is that Flash installer is behaving as a typical malware:

- you don't see which version you are installing;
- you can't check if this is a valid installer;
- you can't check if it is fixing any of your bugs;
- you can't check if it risk to break something within your working environment.

Since all versions since many years have goten the same window look, it is too easy to make a fake one.
These are bad practice of course, since no user will be able to disambiguate a normal Flash Player installer from a real malware.
Personnal point of vue:
I consider this software as a basically risky one developped by a
company Adobe which doesn't care of customers, quality and security.

Comment: All of this is true, but I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: @BAR: tried to improve toward a real answer.

Comment: Better now.  I believe i had disabled ghostery just incase.  Did it continue to run?

Comment: I advise you to keep Ghostery (ad: it is a great tool). The real culprit is Adobe Flash Player installer.
Just open Ghostery, and slide the button blocking `Ominture tracker`.